# How to query mongodb with 'equality' in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have following BSON in Mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52a30bdfaaa83ba83c25c0f3"),
    "course" : {
        "course_name" : "Java EE",
        "description" : "Java Enterprise Edition"
    },
    "first_name" : "Lucy",
    "last_name" : "Hill",
    "gender" : "female"
}
```

I want to find all the document which has "course_name" = "Java EE". In java, I had tried this code but it didn't seem to be working.

```
DBCollection table = db.getCollection("Students"); //my Collection
BasicDBObject courseNameDBObject = new BasicDBObject() 
            .append("course", new BasicDBObject("course_name", "Java EE"));
DBCursor cursor = table.find(courseNameDBObject);
while(cursor.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DBCollection table = db.getCollection("Students"); //my Collection
BasicDBObject courseNameDBObject = new BasicDBObject("course.course_name", "Java EE") ;
DBCursor cursor = table.find(courseNameDBObject);
while(cursor.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

You can use `.` to access fields within a sub document.

[Official documentation on querying](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/)